# Benchmark and Speed up this Python code

Tags: python, numpy

Does anyone know why test1b() is so much faster than test1a()? How do you identify which line is the bottleneck and choose the alternative function to speed it up? Please share your experience

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

def test1a():
    cols = 13
    rows = 10000000
    raw_data = np.random.randint(2, size=cols * rows).reshape(rows, cols)
    col_names = ['v01', 'v02', 'v03', 'v04', 'v05', 'v06', 'v07',
                 'v08', 'v09', 'v10', 'v11', 'v12', 'outcome']
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=col_names)
    df['v11'] = df['v03'].apply(lambda x: ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'][np.random.randint(4)])
    df['v12'] = df['v03'].apply(lambda x: ['p1', 'p2'][np.random.randint(2)])
    return df


def test1b():
    cols = 13
    rows = 10000000
    raw_data = np.random.randint(2, size=(rows,cols))
    col_names = ['v01', 'v02', 'v03', 'v04', 'v05', 'v06', 'v07',
                 'v08', 'v09', 'v10', 'v11', 'v12', 'outcome']
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=col_names)
    df['v11'] = np.take(
        np.array(['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'], dtype=object),
        np.random.randint(4, size=rows))
    df['v12'] = np.take(
        np.array(['p1', 'p2'], dtype=object),
        np.random.randint(2, size=rows))
    return df


start_time = time.time()
test1a()
t1a = time.time() - start_time

start_time = time.time()
test1b()
t1b = time.time() - start_time

print("Test1a: {}sec, Test1b: {}sec".format(t1a, t1b))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that's slowing you down is the pandas `apply` function.
You could profile it with the ipython %timeit function, just comparing

```
%timeit df['v11'] = df['v03'].apply(lambda x: ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'][np.random.randint(4)])
```

to

```
%timeit df['v11'] = np.take(
    np.array(['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'], dtype=object),
    np.random.randint(4, size=rows))
```

Ultimately `pandas.apply` isn't able to vectorize your code the way the numpy implementation can, and results in a lot of overhead in figuring out dtypes and re-invoking the python interpreter at each iteration.